# yaml-cpp, YAML::Node, and a template operator >>

Tags: c++, templates, yaml-cpp

I'm making some kind of serialization using [yaml-cpp](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/). For this to work each class has to declare a method using the signature:

```
template <typename T> void Serialize(T& s);
```

That `T` is a different class when saving and loading. The two class's interface is the same, but I can't make an abstract base class, since most methods are templates. This part is working correctly. I've tried to hook it up with `YAML::Node`'s `operator>>` and `YAML::Emitter`'s `operator<<`.

For `operator<<`, I have a working solution, albeit very cruel one. First declare a superclass for all serializable classes:

```
template <typename T> class Serializable {};
```

Then I can use the following `operator<<`:

```
template <typename T>
YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter& out,
                          Serializable<T>& val)
{
    Serializer serializer(out);
    reinterpret_cast<T*>(&val)->Serialize(serializer);
    return out;
}
```

This works so far, even though that `reinterpret_cast` looks pretty scary, and I'm not sure if it's even legal. I've tried the same for `operator>>`, but it didn't work. It looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
void operator>>(const YAML::Node& node,
                Serializable<T>& val)
{
    Deserializer deserializer(node);
    reinterpret_cast<T*>(&val)->Serialize(deserializer);
}
```

But gcc (4.6.2) and clang(2.9) both ignore it, and use the `operator>>` defined in nodeimp.h (part of yaml-cpp):

```
template <typename T>
inline void operator >> (const Node& node, T& value) {
    if(!ConvertScalar(node, value))
        throw InvalidScalar(node.m_mark);
}
```

So my question is: how should I solve this? Things I absolutely want is to only have a single method for both serialization and deserialization, and to be able to use >> and <<, like if it was a normal type supported by yaml-cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, about `reinterpret_cast`: you actually want `static_cast`. In your case, you know that `val` *is* a `T` (not just a `Serializable<T>`), so you can cast it directly.

Here, I'm assuming you're declaring your classes like

```
class Foo: public Serializable<Foo> { ... };
```

`reinterpret_cast` will interpret the *bytes* of `val` as a `T`, which isn't guaranteed to work, but probably works in your case because you have single inheritance and `Serializable<T>` doesn't add any member variables.

Next, on to your real problem: this is a bug in yaml-cpp, and it's now fixed ([r52790a15757d](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/source/detail?r=52790a15757d) if you're keeping up with the mercurial repository, and see http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=126 for the issue I opened).

With the above fix, I believe your code should work. If you don't keep up with the repository, then the diff is pretty small - you can patch it in your version of yaml-cpp.

Comment: odd, I've tried `static_cast`, and it didn't work, but now it works. (Maybe I tried to cast to T, and not T*?). Anyway your patch works great, thanks for the fix.